# Unable to complete SST transfer due to "WSREP: SST position can't be set in past." error

Tags: mariadb, galera

I am using "MariaDB 10.3.8" and "MariaBackup" for state transfer.wsrep_sst_method=Mariabackup.

I have a donor node and "galera_new_cluster" is running. I want to add another node(joiner) to the cluster. After the mariabackup SST transfer finishes, I receive the error as follows

`WSREP: SST position can't be set in past.`

1. What's kind of error is this?
2. How can I solve this?

here is the log Joiner:

```
2019-02-13  9:57:54 0 [Note] WSREP: Signalling provider to continue.
2019-02-13  9:57:54 0 [Warning] WSREP: SST position can't be set in past. Requested: 194, Current:  123717.
2019-02-13  9:57:54 0 [Warning] WSREP: Can't continue.
2019-02-13  9:57:54 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Are the clocks properly synced and are the settings consistent?

Comment: Yes, time synced. I could solve it :).i have to change manually seq number in donor node

Comment: Could you give us an idea of how you did that?

Comment: please follow this link.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codership-team/HVl5emCJEIw